# enhanced loop is not printing correctly

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm trying to use an enhanced for loop to print out my data from an array but it comes out with rubbish. Please help, thank you in advance.

ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

```
    //For loop to input names
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {   
        System.out.print("Enter name of Player " + i +":");
        String startName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter jersey number of Player " + i +":");
        int playNum = keyboard.nextInt();
        startName = keyboard.nextLine();

        //Make objects and add to array
        HockeyPlayer p = new HockeyPlayer(startName, playNum);
        array.add(p);
    }
    keyboard.close();
```

The code for the loop is:

```
System.out.println("The players are...");

        for(HockeyPlayer val : array)
        {
            System.out.println(val);
        }
```

It ends up printing something like this... How can I fix it?

```
Please enter the names and jersey numbers of 3 hockey players.
Enter name of Player 0:Joeasdas
Enter jersey number of Player 0:213
Enter name of Player 1:Baskdja
Enter jersey number of Player 1:121
Enter name of Player 2:djasklaj
Enter jersey number of Player 2:455
The players are...
HockeyPlayer@3f84246a
HockeyPlayer@7c72cbb9
HockeyPlayer@549d1e83
```

Comment: Why posting the same question twice?

Comment: Someone told me if I had another question that I should make a different post. In the last one I couldn't add objects to an array.
In this one, I can't seem to get it to print  correctly.

Comment: I wrote an answer for this exact question 20 minutes ago, when you first posted it.  I was just posting my answer when you deleted the question.  Sorry, I can't be bothered typing it all again.  If you want people to help you, don't mess them around.

Comment: I apologize for the bother, David. When I posted it the first time I realized I forgot a section of my code, so that is why I deleted it so fast. Once again, sorry.

Comment: You know there's an edit function, right?

Comment: Sorry I just joined this site. Now I know! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the toString method in the HockeyPlayer class. For example:

```
public String toString() {
    return  number+" "+name;
}
```

Comment: Hi Joni. Can you explain how this work a bit more? I tried using it but it only seems to print out the number.

Comment: That's because you create the players with an empty name. See how you assign startName twice?

Answer (score 0):

HockeyPlayer@3f84246a indicates that you don't have the toString method overriden.
Just declare a method like this in HockeyPlayer:

```
@Override 
public String toString()
{ 
  return "Your String"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the `toString` method from `Object` class print the class name and some other nums, and you can override it to print something you want it to print, so simply do something like this:

```
  @Override 
   public String toString()
  { 
      return "returning something"; 
  }
```